# Proving that for any Differentiable distribution $F(x)$, an expression is increasing in $x$?

Tags: probability-distributions, taylor-expansion

I am guessing that for a continuous random variable on $[0,1]$, 
$$
U(x)=\Big[x F(x) + \int_x^1 (1-t)f(t)dt\Big]x
$$
is increasing for any distributions, because I can show 
$$
U'(x)=2xF+x^2f+\int_x^1 (1-t)f_tdt-x(1-x)f \geq 0
$$ 
for a particular family, the power distribution family 
$$
F(x)=x^a, a\geq 0.
$$
That is,
$$
\begin{align}
U'_x(x;a)
&=2x^{a+1}+ax^{a+1}+\int_x^1  t^a dt
-(1-x)x^a-x(1-x)ax^{a-1}\\
&=1-(1+a)^2 x^a + (1+2a)(2+a)x^{a+1} \\
&\geq 0 \end{align}
$$ 
for any $x\in [0,1]$ and $a\geq 0$.

But without a specific functional form for $F(x)$, the sign of $U'(x)$ seems undetermined.

However, we can use Taylor expansion to represent almost any differentiable $F(x)$ on $[0,1]$. 
$$F(x)=\sum_{a=1}^\infty \gamma_a x^a \geq 0,\quad \sum_{a=1}^\infty \gamma_a= 1,  \quad f(x)=\sum_{a=1}^\infty   \gamma_a ax^{a-1} \geq 0$$
where$\gamma_a$ are constants. Of course, the inequalities  hold for any $x \in [0,1]$.

We find, under this construction of $F(x)$
$$\begin{align}
U'_{general}(x;a) &= \sum_{a=1}^\infty \gamma_a \left[1-(1+a)^2 x^a + (1+2a)(2+a)x^{a+1} \right]\\
&=\sum_{a=1}^\infty \gamma_a U'_x(x;a)
\end{align}$$

But again, it is really challenging to determine the sign of $U'_{general}(x;a)$, even for a particular case: when $x=1$, 
$$
U'_{general}(1;a) =\sum_{a=1}^\infty \gamma_a (2+a).
$$
Can anyone give some hints on proving $U'_{general}(x;a) \geq 0$ for any $x \in [0,1]$, or for some other general class of distribution function, or distributions with properties such as Log-Concave, increasing $hazard \,\, rate \equiv \frac{f(x)}{1-F(x)}$?
Or find a counter example?

Comment: It seems to me there is a sign error in your computation of $U'$ - it should be $+x(1-x)f(x)$ instead of $-$.

Comment: @Math1000, I think the computation is correct. According to $\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^b h(t)dt = -h(x)$, when $h(t)=(1-t)f(t)$, we get $-(1-x)f(x)$.

Comment: Ah, $x$ is the lower limit of the integral, so your integral above is equivalent to $-\int_b^x h(t)\ \mathsf dt$. An oversight on my part.

Comment: I think this is false for the uniform distribution on $[0,\tfrac14]$ but the calculations are a bit messy, so please double-check this.  In general (if I haven't botched something) you want a distribution which has little or no mass on $[\tfrac12,1]$ and reasonably large values of $f(x)$ for some small $x$ where $F(x)$ is close to $1$.

Comment: @Erick Wong, you see, I have shown $U'(m)\geq 0$ for $F=m^a, a\geq 0$. When $a=1$, the distribution is uniform. So I guess there are some errors in your calculations.

Comment: @user2966729 You are mistaken.  I said uniform distribution on $[0,\tfrac14]$ where $f(x) = 4$ on the support of $f$.  This is $F(m) = \min(1,4m)$, which you have not tested.

Comment: @Erick Wong, oh sorry and thanks, let me check.

Comment: @Erick Wong, I think there are errors in your calculations. When $x\in[0,\frac{1}{4}]$, $U'(x)=2 - 8 x + 18 x^2$, which reaches a minimum at $x^*=\frac{2}{9}$, where $U'(x^*)=\frac{10}{9}$. But thanks for inspirations.

Comment: @user2966729 Thanks for checking, but did you take into account the fact that $f(x) = 0$ for $x > \tfrac14$ so that $\int_x^1 = \int_x^{1/4}$?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26850/discussion-between-user2966729-and-erick-wong).

Comment: @ErickWong, Oh, right, I didn't take into account of that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it doesn't help to try random distributions to gain insight into an inequality like this (and Taylor expansion is not effective, since you have no control over the coefficients).  We need to look at extremal cases, but first we need to understand what makes $U(x)$ tick.

First, use integration by parts to rewrite $\int_x^1 (1-t) f(t)\, dt$ as $(x-1) F(x) + \int_x^1 F(t)\, dt$.  So

$$U(x) = \bigg[ (2x-1) F(x) + \int_x^1 F(t)\, dt \bigg] x,$$
$$U'(x) = (2x-1) F(x) + \int_x^1 F(t)\, dt + \big[ (2x-1) f(x) + 2F(x) - F(x) \big] x, \\
 = (3x-1) F(x) + (2x-1)x f(x) + \int_x^1 F(t)\, dt.$$

The last term is bounded above by $(1-x)$, so

$$U'(x) \le (3x-1) F(x) + (2x-1)x f(x) + (1-x).$$  Now note that the right-hand-side is negative at $x = \tfrac13$ for any distribution where $f(\tfrac13) > 6$.

Comment: @user2966729 Ah, thanks!  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Following Erick's suggestion, here's a plot of $U(x)$ when $X$ has a uniform distribution on the interval $1/3\pm 1/10.$

[image]

Comment: I think I can and would like to restrict the distribution function to be differentiable everywhere on $[0,1]$, and even no digenerated points everywhere except at $0$ and $1$. But I am really thankful for your inputs!

Comment: @user2966729 It would be easy to smooth out this $F$ and still get a $U(x)$ that is not monotone.

Comment: Could you please show me that? I am elementary on such statistics theory. And could you please try to give a more general condition (than $F=x^a$) or other conditions such that $U(x)$ is increasing for any $x\in[0,1]$?

Comment: @user2966729 You can see that $U(x)$ will not be monotone if $f$ ever gets too large (for small $x$).  I think a sufficient condition is that $f(x) < 2F(x)/(1-2x)$ for all $x<\tfrac 12$, and I believe this is fairly close to necessary, in that if $f(x_0) > 2F(x_0)/(1-2x_0)$ for some $x_0 < \tfrac12$ then there exists a counterexample $g$ which agrees with $f$ on the interval $[0,x_0]$.

Comment: @ErickWong, Thanks a lot! Following your suggestions, I find for right-skewed enough beta distributions, there are small $x$ such that $U'<0$, as expected, within a small interval and the values are slightly negative. Acutally, I am trying to show another function $H(x)$ is increasing. $U'>0$ is a sufficient condition, which is a deflated $H'(x)$. From another  source of indirect proof, I find $H'(x)$ must be positive for any distribution. In fact, I want to directly prove $H'(x)>0$ from a first order differential equation of $H(x)$. Can you help me on that problem?

Comment: @ErickWong, if you are interested, please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393735/prove-from-a-first-order-differential-equation-that-for-any-distribution-a-func

Comment: @Bryon, the plot is misleading since now $x\in[1/3-1/10,1/3+1/10]$. As the plot on this interval suggests, $U(x)$ is well above 0.